# Difference between 'Windows Console Application' and 'Empty Project' in VS C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

If I'm making a simple C++ program, such as connecting to a database, which option should I choose in Visual Studio 2017 as a Visual C++ template?

**Windows Console Application**
*or*
**Empty Project**?

Will a Windows Console Application based program run only on windows where as an empty project one will run on many OS'?

Comment: the only issues  you will face are import issues and when you read or write files as dir will differ on unix but you can overcome it by just creating a simple template to switch. Better option would be to create universal apps thr is a option in VS to do that.

Comment: *Windows Console Application* just does some extra tasks for you to start working on it right away, based on *Empty Project*.

Comment: If you want a database to work on multiple OSs you want to look into opensource frameworks or database libraries. Don't use the windows only apis. Qt is one such framework with database support across many operating systems.

Comment: If you want a lightweight database perhaps sqlite is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, I've already decided I'm using libpqxx for PostgreSQL. This should be fine shouldn't it?

Comment: That should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "Window's Console Application" program has stuff added to your project to make it run smoother with the Window's command prompt. However, even if you create an "Empty Project", the compiled version will not run on another OS, by default. You will have to recompile for each OS you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use a console application, it will already have the main function and such in there.  It is what you would use for a "hello world" program.
If you start from an empty project you're just going to have to create a similar .cpp file anyway.